# howt to generate AST tree form (not in JSON form) from Solidity File (.sol)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, contract-debugging

I have .sol file and want to generate AST only from .sol file. My scenario is that at the command line (**after installation some package**), I just have to give a command like `package_command --AST [from MyContract.sol]` and that command gives me the output at the console or in the file. I have search a lot, but could not found any easy solution.

Is it possible to get/draw/print AST  actual in tree form, not in JSON form? Kindly guide me with the easiest available options.

Comment: What do you mean by "tree form"? JSON is already a tree structure.

Comment: @Morten "tree form" means visually tree diagram .. not as presented in JSON form (key and value )